# Combine 2 tables using the nearest timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, combinations

I need to generate the following query result in mySQL:

```
          lat1       lng1       timestamp1
canid1                                      diff_timestamp1 
canid2                                      diff_timestamp1 
canid3                                      diff_timestamp1 
......                                        .........
          lat2       lng2       timestamp2
canid1                                      diff_timestamp2 
canid2                                      diff_timestamp2 
canid3                                      diff_timestamp2 
......                                        .........
```

In values for example:

```
  canid      lat          lng    gps.timestamp  difference_to_gps_timestamp
  NULL   +52.220961    +9.416273     550                   NULL
0x90FE6FFE  NULL         NULL        NULL                   50
0x8CF004FE  NULL         NULL        NULL                   60
0x90FE6FFE  NULL         NULL        NULL                   90
  NULL   +52.220960    +9.416273     1550                   NULL
0x8CF004FE  NULL         NULL        NULL                   50
0x8CF004FE  NULL         NULL        NULL                   50
```

Is this even possible? Maybe with the Join variantes?

The data i get from the two tables gps and can. They are connected over the table log using the gps/can.logid = log.id.
The problem is, that every 'can' entry has it's own timestamp that is not the same as the 'gps' timestamp so every 'can' entry should directed to the nearest 'gps' position using the timestamp.

CAN-data:

```
id   canid    logid     data         timestamp
1   0x90FE6FFE  1   000000C533BB87FF    600
2   0x8CF004FE  1   007D7D9C6300F07D    610
3   0x90FE6FFE  1   000000C5E6C683FF1   640
4   0x8CF004FE  1   007D7DF03A00F07D1   1500
5   0x90FE6FFE  1   000000C59AD283FF1   1600
```

id: primary key   logid: foreignkey from log

GPS:

```
id    lat         lng     logid      timestamp
1   52.220961   9.416273    1            562
2   52.220960   9.416273    1           1550
3   52.220960   9.416273    1           2551
4   52.220960   9.416273    1           3546
5   52.220959   9.416274    1           4548
```

LOG:

```
id    logdate       logtime      vehicleid
1     2017-03-22    10:56:54        1
2     2017-03-22    11:32:43        1
```

I used the following select to get the nearest timestamp from gps for a can-entry. The 3000 symbolizes the timestamp of an can-entry. But I have no idea how to change it to get the result i want.

```
SELECT timestamp, ABS( timestamp - 3000 ) AS distance FROM (
(
    SELECT timestamp
    FROM `gps`
    WHERE timestamp >=3000
    ORDER BY timestamp
    LIMIT 6
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT timestamp
    FROM `gps`
    WHERE timestamp < 3000
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 6
)
) AS n
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1
```

I would be very happy about your help

Comment: I don't understand what you want to produce.  A SQL result set consists of a set of rows that all have the same columns.

Comment: Your example data should have values that indicate their type and format, not "labels". You should also show what you have tried.

Comment: So i edit it. I hope now the problem is clear.